# angular-kendo UI, NumericTextBox, cant display zero value

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendonumerictextbox

When I set initial value of variable to "0", then NumericTextBox field cant show this value.

Code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="value" kendo-numeric-text-box>
            <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="value">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value=0;
};
```

In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Skryabind/3gyYW/) you can see that simple text field displays zero value, but kendo NumericTextBox is empty. But if you type zero again in simple text field, then zero will be in kendo field too.
I think this is a bug, how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it is a bug, you can either ask the maintainer of angular-kendo to fix it, or you can fix it yourself. It's a relatively simple fix, I think, because the link function doesn't distinguish between model values 0 and `undefined`. So you'd need to make sure the widget's value method is only called with `null` if the value is actually `null` or undefined:

```
if (typeof ngModel.$viewValue !== 'undefined') {
    widget.value(ngModel.$viewValue);
} else {
    widget.value(null);
}
```

Here's a demo with a [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/LvR3f/3/) (links to a fork of angular-kendo, mind you).

Comment: Thank you! Will you make a pull request, or I must to fix this in my fork and then make a pull request?

Comment: actually, it looks like this was [already fixed](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues/124), even though only in the angular-kendo.js file in the root